# Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.id:

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I tried to execute a testcase for login page in **flipkart** application on android device using appium.

I am getting inconsistent error as follows:

> Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for presence of element located by:
>   By.id: com.flipkart.android:id/et_password.

**Note:** I have used `implicit wait` and `explicit wait` and I have given **time duration from 30 to 70 seconds**. The test is getting passed occasionally.
Please provide me a solution for this

My code:

```
cab.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
cab.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Mac");
cab.setCapability("platformName", "android");
cab.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1.1");
cab.setCapability("deviceName", "70af41a");
cab.setCapability("app", "/Users/xxx/Downloads/flipkart.apk");
cab.setCapability("appPackage", "com.flipkart.android"); //Replace with your app's package
cab.setCapability("appActivity", ".SplashActivity"); //Replace with app's Activity
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cab);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

element = driver.findElement(By.id("com.flipkart.android:id/mobileNo"));
element.sendKeys("1234567897");

//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);;

MobileElement signup = driver.findElement(By.id("com.flipkart.android:id/btn_msignup"));
signup.click();
WebDriverWait waitforsignup = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
waitforsignup.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("com.flipkart.android:id/et_password"))); 
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Isn't that what you've told the code to do. Time out after 30 secs `WebDriverWait(driver, 30)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.presenceOfElementLocated()` try `.visibilityOfElementLocated()`. .presence checks if the element is in the DOM while .visibility goes a step further and makes sure that the element is visible. Selenium will not interact with an element that is not visible so that may be your issue.